# returning to python3 with fg messes up arrow keys interpretation

Tags: python, terminal, keyboard, jobs, readline

When I'm in gnome-terminal (or Konsole) and run `python3`, arrow keys work as expected but when I `CTRL+Z` so I come back to terminal, then `fg` to bring-up `python3` again, arrow keys are printed like `^[[A` .
How can I fix this?

Comment: @snakecharmerb I guess it has something to do with python's signal handling. See  Thomas Dickey's explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this before the **`fg`** command:

```
tput smkx
```

to put the keypad (and cursor-keys) into application mode (see [xterm FAQ](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_arrows)).

The question seems to indicate that python3 enables application mode, but does not handle signals (such as [**`SIGCONT`**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04)).

Comment: I guess this `tput smkx` command is too cryptic for every time running before `fg`. So is this a bug in python3 REPL side?

Comment: yes - similar issues have been reported, always indicating bugs in python's command-interpreter.